# React use state in different components

Tags: reactjs

I am creating weather app . I have a 'search' component for (my form, axios )and in this component i store my data in state. When I submit this form I want to load ANOTHER PAGE with next component.. and my question is how can i use data from 'search component' in other component which will be load when the form will submit
So basically i want to submit my form then reload another page with Weather Component and then i want to move my data from Search to Weather Component. In Weather component a will set my background and other data

```html
mport React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


const KEY = 'fdc0a9d5321ee73e70535ed7d7e052ce'


class Search extends Component {
    state = {
        value: null,
        city: null,
        temp: null
    }
    onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            value: e.target.value
        })
    }
    onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${this.state.value}&appid=${KEY}&units=metric`)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    city: this.state.value,
                    temp: res.data.main.temp
                })
                console.log(this.state)
            })
    }

    render() {
    return (
       
            <div className="Search">
                 <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <input onChange={this.onChange}></input>
                    <button>Submit</button>
                 </form>
                 
            </div>
        
    )
}
}
export default Search

import React from 'react';


const Weather = () => {
        
    
    return (
        <div>
           <h1>Lorem</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Weather
```

Comment: You need to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) or use something like [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: also i want to load new page after submit with new Component. How can i do that

Comment: Please remember for your future posts to not post any API-Keys as other People can use them too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try toggling the component to achieve this.
Try something like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


const KEY = 'fdc0a9d5321ee73e70535ed7d7e052ce'


class Search extends Component {
    state = {
        value: null,
        city: null,
        temp: null
    }
    onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            value: e.target.value
        })
    }
    onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${this.state.value}&appid=${KEY}&units=metric`)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    city: this.state.value,
                    temp: res.data.main.temp
                })
    const data={
                    city: this.state.value,
                    temp: res.data.main.temp
                }
    this.props.callback(data)
                console.log(this.state)
            })
    }

    render() {
    return (
       
            <div className="Search">
                 <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <input onChange={this.onChange}></input>
                    <button>Submit</button>
                 </form>
                 
            </div>
        
    )
}
}
export default Search

import React from 'react';
import Search from './Search'

const Weather = () => {
const[formSubmitted,setFormSubmitted]=useState('false)
        
    const callBackHandler=(data)=>{
      setFormSubmitted(true)
       //do something with the data
    }
    return (
        <div>
    {formSubmitted? <h1>Lorem</h1>:<Search callback={(data)=>callBackHandler(data)}/>}
          
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Weather
```